# Initialize delegate with anonymous function

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

I have some hardware that exists as various models,  and am writing software that will control it with various GUIs. I have a class representing the hardware, which has properties such as voltage, rate, size, etc. I would like to simplify access to these properties by creating a class like the following:

```
    public class CProperty
    {
        public CProperty(string name, Func<object> get, Action<object> set)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.get = get;
            set = set;
        }
        private string name;
        public Func<object> get;
        public Action<object> set;
        private object value;
    }
```

Then I could initialize an array of these as follows:

```
    public CProperty[] Properties = new CProperty[]
    {
        new CProperty(
            "name1",
            new Func<float>(() => value),
            new Action<float>((v) => value = v)
            ),
    };
```

The array could then be made into a collection class with an indexer that uses the property name as the index.
But when I try to do this, in the array initialization the field "value" is not in scope in the initializers for the set and get functions, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Whats the point of this? I mean you could define `get` and `set` in `CProperty`, they're "classic" getters and setters. Why do you want to define them "outside"?

Comment: You can't convert a `Func<float>` to a `Func<object>` nor you can convert the `Action<float>` to `Action<object>`

Comment: Covariance and contravariance don't play well with value types.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a `Func<float>` to a `Func<object>` nor you can convert an `Action<float>` to `Action<object>`. This because covariance and contravariance don't play well with value types (in the end covariance and contravariance are sleight-of-hand, not real conversions between types, and so require that both types have the same memory layout... a reference is a reference, so it is easy to do covariance/contravariance between two references, but a `float` is a value type, that is something very different from an `object` that is a reference type)

And in both cases you should add a parameter of type `CProperty` to the `Func/Action`, like `Func<CProperty, float>(cp => cp.value)`, but `value` must be `public`... This because anonymous methods are "static", they don't have free access to the `this` reference, so you have to pass it as a parameter...

```
public class CProperty
{
    public CProperty(string name, Func<CProperty, object> get, Action<CProperty, object> set)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.get = get;
        this.set = set;
    }
    private string name;
    public Func<CProperty, object> get;
    public Action<CProperty, object> set;
    public object value;
}

var properties = new CProperty[]
{
    new CProperty(
        "name1",
        new Func<CProperty, object>(cp => cp.value),
        new Action<CProperty, object>((cp, v) => cp.value = v)
    ),
};
```

or you can even capture the `this`:

```
public class CProperty
{
    public CProperty(string name, Func<CProperty, Func<object>> get, Func<CProperty, Action<object>> set)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.get = get(this);
        this.set = set(this);
    }
    private string name;
    public Func<object> get;
    public Action<object> set;
    public object value;
}   

var properties = new CProperty[]
{
    new CProperty(
        "name1",
        cp => new Func<object>(() => cp.value),
        cp => new Action<object>((v) => cp.value = v)
    ),
};
```

In the end I think you are quite far from what you want... you'll have to return to the design board with the `CProperty` class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you are going to achieve here.

Looking at the code, I could say that you are trying to reimplement a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) concept — you have backing field `value` and getter with setter expressed by delegates.

Looking at description,

> collection class with an indexer that uses the property name as the index

I could say that you would like to access properties of your objects by their name at runtime — this is possible with use of [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

At least, I'm able to answer this part

> But when I try to do this, in the array initialization the field "value" is not in scope in the initializers for the set and get functions, and I don't understand why.

As compiler suggests, this thing is about scoping. It makes sense to distinguish between [Lexical and dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) for that case.
Lexical or static scope is defined by means of location in the source code of your program, while dynamic scope is built upon actual execution path. C# has lexical scoping and for that reason your delegates, which are declared from the outside of  `CProperty` class, are not able to access `value` field, despite the fact that they are actually invoked inside.

`value` is a field and it is in scope of `CProperty` class thus it's visible to members of this class only. Outer world can access this field via `CProperty` instance (but only if you make field `public`).

```
var prop = new CProperty(/*ctor parameters*/)
var value = prop.value;
```